# Delete references to nonexistent databases in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to delete references to two nonexistent .sdf databases listed in my solution but nothing happens when I select delete, exclude from project, or detach. I think I made the mistake of deleting the databases in Explorer instead of from VS. [Here](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ARK-lGsGcfk/TtqHCXz9kII/AAAAAAAAAW0/hrYzUFwzdRM/s181/DatabasesBad.PNG) is what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the csproj file in Notepad...

Comment: The csproj file didn't seem to have any references to databases. What should I look for?

Comment: I did this while VS2010 was open and now have an infinite loop of generic ("Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error.") error messages. Awesome!